# Make java web application available for external network

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, networking

I've built a simple java web application and have deployed on Apache Tomcat.
I would like to show the app to friends using my internet ip address but it aways get timed out error. Let's examine de cases:

1) By default, I can access it using localhost:8080 or ip-lan:8080. When I try to access it using my internet ip I get an error, but it is totally expected, since I didn't even configure router yet.

2)Once the virtual server is configured properly to point to my local ip address when receiving any request on port 8080, I can access it nicely.

3) Anyone outside my local network can access my application even using my internet ip address. Get the error connection timed out.

Do you know what I am missing?

Using Win10, Firewall disabled, antivirus disabled, virtual server enabled to redirect any request on port 8080 that come from internet ip address to my local ip address where tomcat is running.

***UPDATE***

When change the port 8080 to another, for example 8085, it works nicely.
Just open file conf/server.xml and change all 8080 for 8085.
It seems that my IPS use the porta externally for something.

Comment: Your ISP could filter this port. Tried another?

Comment: Haven't tried another yet, I will, and give the feedback here.

Comment: covener, misteriously when change the port it seems work fine, thanks.

Comment: Probably blocking it as a common proxy port